# Moving to Webpack2 from Gulp.js

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to move from gulp.js to webpack2 and by the way trying to study React. So I've created small "hello world" app with Leaflet.js and React.

But just right after start I have some questions about webpack.
I want to get following structure:

```
app/
    dist/  <-- folder with built app
        images/
            vendor/
                vendor-image1.png
                vendor-image2.png
                ...
            app/
                my-image1.png
                my-image2.png
                ...
        js/
            vendor.js
            app.js
        css/
            vendor.css
            app.css
        index.html

    src/  <-- folder with my app source
        components/
            App/
                index.js
            MyMap/
                index.js
                styles.css
        index.js
```

To achieve this structure with gulp I need only to create separate tasks for vendor and app resources (like `vendor-css`, `vendor-js`, `app-css`, etc.), manually list all files to process and put proper paths to `dest`, but how can I achieve this structure with webpack?

Second question about some resources that are added in runtime. For example Leaflet adds `marker-shadow.png` in runtime and currently I've got 404 for it, so how can I deal with such assets?

Comment: Do you **really** need this structure in your `dist` folder?

Comment: @errata yeap, I'm moving existing app